# Python 3 - Tkinter nameError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

NameError: name 'onOpen' is not defined

There is something wrong with the command function. I am not sure what I did wrong here. I had the code tested before the onOpen function and it works fine.

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Application(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) 
        self.pack() 
        self.createWidgets()

    def onOpen():
        """ Ask the user to choose a file and update the values of label change button"""
        button_label.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ()))

    def createWidgets(self):

        #instruction label
        self.labelInstruct = tk.Label(self, text="Instructions:", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.labelInstruct = tk.Label(self, text="All you have to do is insert the file and save it.\n The conversion is instant", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.labelInstruct.pack()

        #insertfile button
        self.ifbut = tk.Button(self, text="Insert File", command=onOpen)
        self.ifbut.pack()

        button_label = tk.StringVar(self)
        text = tk.Label(self, textvariable = button_label)
        text.pack()

        #save button
        self.saveLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Save File", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.saveLabel.pack()
        self.saveButton = tk.Button(self)
        self.saveButton.pack()

        #quit button
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
            command=self.quit) 
        self.quitButton.pack()

app = Application() 
app.master.title('Sample application') 
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that there are many problems with the way this code is written I am only going to point out a few of them and tackle the main question from the OP.

Lets start with the fact that you need to define the main window with something like `root = tk.Tk()` and you also need to make sure all your methods in your class have the argument `self` as the first argument.

Also any variable you are defining also should have self so that the class can interact with it. This (`button_label`) for example should be `self.button_label`.

There is no reason to use return the way you are trying to in the `onOpen(self):` method. Return does not work like that. Return is there so you can return a value to something that is calling the function/method to be used for something else and is not for setting the value of something.

Note that I also add the `root` window variable to the `app = Application(root)` line. This lets us pass the main window into the class.

all and all the following should work for the `onOpen(self):` function but the rest still needs some work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class Application(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack() 
        self.createWidgets()

    def onOpen(self):
        """ Ask the user to choose a file and update the values of label change button"""
        self.button_label.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ()))

    def createWidgets(self):

        #instruction label
        self.labelInstruct = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Instructions:", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.labelInstruct = tk.Label(self.parent, text="All you have to do is insert the file and save it.\n The conversion is instant", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.labelInstruct.pack()

        #insert file button
        self.ifbut = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Insert File", command = self.onOpen)
        self.ifbut.pack()

        self.button_label = tk.StringVar()
        self.text = tk.Label(self.parent, textvariable = self.button_label)
        self.text.pack()

        #save button
        self.saveLabel = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Save File", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.saveLabel.pack()
        self.saveButton = tk.Button(self.parent, text = "Save")
        self.saveButton.pack()

        #quit button
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.parent, text='Quit', command=self.quit) 
        self.quitButton.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root) 
app.master.title('Sample application') 
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the function value as below:

```
def onOpen():
    """ Ask the user to choose a file and update the values of label change button"""
    return button_label.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ()))
```

Comment: There’s many issues in the OP’s code, that’s not one of them. You **do not** return `tkinter.label.set()`

Comment: Guess, i gave a wrong suggestion. What is the correct recommendation?

Comment: Since there’s so many problems, I would rather flag this question as Too Broad. But.... Just dealing with the NameError, the `command` argument should be changed to `command=self.onOpen` since `onOpen` is an instance method. And that because it’s an instance method, the `onOpen` should accept the `self` arg. `def onOpen(self):`. There will still some errors left for the OP to figure out themself.

Comment: And the reason why your solution is wrong because `.set()` is an inplace method. Adding a return statement’s just making it return None. Just like how you don’t do this: `return list.append()`

Comment: Yes, i agree with what you said. Since onOpen is an instance method, the function should be written def onOpen(self) and command parameter should be self.onOpen. Thanks for your attention. Guess i made a comment on a topic that i haven't known well yet.

Comment: But i want to show you an example about returning a function.  Please look at this page. An author returned a function. See the Jonathan Reinharts post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/44352931#44352931 Is this case different than this?

Comment: I think you’ll need to review the difference between returning an in-place operation (some function hat doesn’t return anything) and returning a returned result. `.set()` is an in-place operation while your linked answer `os.path.join()` returns a result (path string). **It’s absolutely not a good practice to return an in-place operation.**

Comment: Yes, you are right, and i appreciate you showing me one of the places I should review.